# Which port to expose for mongoose?

Tags: docker, mongoose

I want to containerise my application which connects to Atlas. However, I am not able to find out which port mongoose uses for connecting, nor how to set it to a custom port of my choice. What should I do?

Comment: standard mongo port is 27017

Comment: You only need to publish ports to accept inbound connections, not to make outbound connections.  "Expose" as a Docker verb doesn't mean a whole lot any more.

Comment: @DavidMaze Alright, thanks! I thought I would need the -p even if I make the outbound requests.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose is an Object Data Modeling (ODM) library for MongoDB and Node.js and does not export any port.
Here is a `mongoose.connect` example, where you can use the port that you configured the `MongoDB` to listen to:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

I assume you are asking what is the standard port that MongoDB listens to: `27017`

Comment: I do know what MongoDB itself listens to, but mongoose does need to use some port for communicating with the outer world, right? If I just put it into docker, it won't be able to reach the MongoDB database anymore because I need to expose a port for it.

Comment: If you want to publish the port of the container on the host machine, you can used the `-p` argument, when you start the container. E.g.: `docker run -p 27017:27017 mongo` where the -p is <sourcePortOnHost>:<destinationPortOnContainer>. The you can connect to localhost:27017 directly from you host machine